# Matrix derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial w} (y^\top g(H(w)) y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to solve a matrix derivative, but I don't really know how to handle the two vectors products I guess. I am not particularly proficient in this kind of calculus so I have been using https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf to help me.

Here is what I have done so far:

Captial letters are matrices.

We have the following:
\begin{equation}
H = L + W,
\end{equation}
where, L is symmetric, and W is diagonal, containing vector $w$ on the diagonal. Hence $H$ is also symmetric and has the following property:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial H^{-2}}{\partial w} = -2 H^{-3} 
\end{equation}

we have:
\begin{equation}
f = y^\top L H^{-2} L y,
\end{equation}
where, y is a vector, and wish to find the derivative of f with regards to $w$.

Let 
\begin{equation}
g(H) = H^{-2}.
\end{equation}
Then I get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= y^\top L \frac{\partial g(H)}{\partial w} L y \\ 
&= y^\top L \text{Tr}(-2H^{-3}) L y \\ 
\end{align*}
Which is meaningless?

Where I used the chainrule:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g(H)}{\partial w_{ij}} = \text{Tr}( \frac{\partial g(H)}{\partial H} \frac{\partial H}{\partial w_{ij}})
\end{equation}

I'm not sure what I have done wrong, but I would be grateful if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, and guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the following symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= -Lyy^TL = A^T \\
V &= H^{-1} = V^T \\
}$$
The main problem with your analysis is that the quantity $\left(\frac{\partial H^{-2}}{\partial w}\right)$ is a third-order tensor, so it cannot possibly be equal to $-2H^{-3}$ as you've assumed.

However, the *differential* of a matrix is just another matrix, and is much easier to work with than a third-order tensor.

Let's start with the differential of the inverse, and then its square.
$$\eqalign{
I &= HV \\
0 &= dH\,V + H\,dV \\ 0 &= V\,dH\,V+dV \\
dV &= -V\,dH\,V \\
\\
V^2 &= V\,V\\
dV^2 &= dV\,V + V\,dV \\ &= -(V\,dH\,V^2+V^2dH\,V) \\
}$$
Next calculate the differential and gradient of the objective function.
$$\eqalign{
f &= y^TLH^{-2}Ly \\&= Lyy^TL:V^2 \\&= -A:V^2 \\
df &= -A:dV^2 \\
 &= +A:(V\,dH\,V^2+V^2dH\,V) \\
 &= (VAV^2:dH)  + (V^2AV:dH) \\
 &= V(VA+AV)V:dH \\
}$$
At this point, note that
$$\eqalign{
H &= L + \operatorname{Diag}(w) \\
dH &= \operatorname{Diag}(dw) \\
}$$
and substitute to obtain
$$\eqalign{
df &= V(VA+AV)V:{\rm Diag}(dw) \\
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(V(VA+AV)V\Big):dw \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(V(VA+AV)V\Big) \\
 &= -{\,\rm diag}\Big(V(VLyy^TL+Lyy^TLV)V\Big) \\
 &= -{\,\rm diag}\Big(H^{-2}Lyy^TLH^{-1}+H^{-1}Lyy^TLH^{-2}\Big) \\
}$$
**NB:** In the above, a colon is used as a convenient notation for the trace operation, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows terms in such a product to be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{A:BC &= AC^T:B \\&= B^TA:C \\&= BC:A \\&= etc}$$
The diag() function extracts the main diagonal of its matrix argument and returns it as a column vector, while the Diag() function takes a vector argument and returns a diagonal matrix.

#### Update

Since you asked about it, here is how the third-order gradient can be calculated.

Start by introducing a third-order tensor ${\cal F}$ and a fourth-order tensor ${\cal E}$ whose components can be written as
$$\eqalign{
{\cal F}_{ijk}
 &= \begin{cases}
  1 \quad&{\rm if\;} i=j=k \\
  0 \quad&{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
{\cal E}_{ijkl}
 &= \begin{cases}
  1 \quad&{\rm if\;} i=k {\rm\;and\,} j=l \\
  0 \quad&{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
These tensors are useful because of the following properties
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Diag}(w) &= {\cal F}\cdot w \\
{\rm diag}(A) &= {\cal F}:A \\
ABC &= \big(A\cdot{\cal E}\cdot C^T\big):B \\
}$$
Applying this to the above differential formula yields
$$\eqalign{
dV^2
 &= -(V\,dH\,V^2+V^2dH\,V) \\
 &= -(V\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V^2+V^2\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V):dH \\
dH^{-2}
 &= -(V\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V^2+V^2\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V):{\cal F}\cdot dw \\
\frac{\partial H^{-2}}{\partial w}
 &= -(V\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V^2+V^2\cdot{\cal E}\cdot V):{\cal F} \\
}$$
where the various dot products with tensors are defined in index notation as
$$\eqalign{
{\cal P} &= {\cal B}:{\cal C} 
\quad&\implies
{\cal P}_{ijmn} &= \sum_k\sum_l{\cal B}_{ijkl}\,{\cal C}_{klmn} \\
{\cal Q} &= {\cal B}\cdot{\cal C} 
&\implies
{\cal Q}_{ijkmnp} &= \sum_l{\cal B}_{ijkl}\,{\cal C}_{lmnp} \\
}$$
Having derived an expression for a typical higher-order tensor gradient, I hope you understand why you will never need it. The *only* reason anyone asks for it, is because they want to use it in a misguided attempt to apply the chain rule.

But instead of the chain rule, one should approach these problems using *differentials*.

Another workable approach is to use *vectorization* (aka column-stacking) to reshape every matrix into a (long) column vector.

Comment: I have read this answer about 5 times now and I think I'm finally starting to understand everything, so thank you very much!

I have an overall question, how do you learn to do this kind of algebra? I haven't found many courses or resources out there that can teach me this, but it would be hugely beneficial to my research.

Secondly, am I correct in thinking that the derivative $\frac{\partial H^{-2}}{\partial w} = - 2 diag(V) * diag(V^2)$

Comment: The standard text is probably _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus and Neudecker.